# How to catch info from html page

Tags: php, html

```
<h1 class="float_left margin_right margin_bottom">Emilio Banfi</h1>
    <div class="clear_left"></div>
    <p><span class="bold_text">Full name:</span> Emilio Banfi
    <br><span class="bold_text">Gender:</span> Male
    <br><span class="bold_text">Born:</span> 1881 in <a href="/olympics/friv/birthplaces.cgi?id=10696">Saronno, Varese, Italy</a>
```

How could I get the following two info using php (I will put them in variables):

```
1881
Saronno, Varese
```

Comment: You can't without `jQuery Ajax`

Answer (score 0):

If you want use only php try add `class` to

```
 <br><span class="bold_text">Born:</span> 
<span class="type">1881</span> in <a href="/olympics/friv/birthplaces.cgi?id=10696"><span class="type">Saronno</span>, 
<span class="type">Varese</span>, Italy</a>
```

And

```
$doc = new DomDocument();
$doc->loadHTMLFile('www.youpage.com');
$thediv = $doc->getElementByClass('type');
echo $thediv->textContent;
```

But better option is use js

Comment: Missing quotes in your `<span>`s. Also, where's the `id`?

Comment: sorry i add `class` instead `id`

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<br><span class="bold_text">Born:</span><span id="get_age"> 1881 </apan>in <a href="/olympics/friv/birthplaces.cgi?id=10696"><span id="get_name">Saronno, Varese, Italy</apan></a>
```

AJAX

```
getRecord();
function getRecord()
{
            var age=jQuery('#get_age').text();
            var name=jQuery('#get_name').text();
            jQuery.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'action.php',
                data:{age:age,name:name},
                async: false,
                success: function (data)
                {
                    alert('success');
                }
            });
}
```

PHP
action.php

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);
```